# como hacer funcionar el ajax correctamente

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, jsp

Cordial saludo

Buenos dias tengo la forma correcta del query realizando una consulta a una base de dato sql server  para me devuelva los valos a mi datatable pero cuando carga me envie un mensaje  DataTables warning: table id=tablaEstudiantes - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

codigo del script

```js
<script>
            
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var tabla = $('#tablaEstudiantes').DataTable({
                        ajax:{
                            method: "POST",
                            url: "../ConsultaEstudiantes",
                            dataSrc: 'datos',
                            dataType:'json'
                            },
                            columns: [
                                {data: "codigo"},
                                {data: "nombre"},
                                {data: "correo"},
                                {data: "telefono"},
                                {data: "estado"},
                                {data: "campus"},
                                {data: "facultad"},
                                {data: "programa"},
                                {data: "semestre"},
                                {data: "modalidad"}                                
                            ]                        
                });
              
                //$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
               
            });
        
        </script>
```

esta es la peticion que estoy realizando por medio del controlador en jsp

> protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
> HttpServletResponse response)
> throws ServletException, IOException {
> response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
> PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
> Connection conn = null ;
> Conexion cn = new Conexion();
> SQLServerPreparedStatement ps =null;
> //PreparedStatement ps = null;
> ResultSet rs = null;
>
> ```
>     try {
>         String consulta = "SELECT estudiantes.Id_estudiante, estudiantes.Name_users, estudiantes.Mail_users,
> ```
>
> estudiantes.Phone_users, estudiantes.Estado_usuario,
> Campus.Name_campus, facultad.Name_faculty, programa.Name_program,
> estudiantes.Semestre, estudiantes.Modalidad FROM estudiantes, Campus,
> facultad, programa WHERE estudiantes.Id_campus = Campus.Id_campus AND
> facultad.Id_faculty=estudiantes.Id_faculty AND
> programa.Id_program=estudiantes.Id_program;";
> conn=cn.getConexion();
> ps=(SQLServerPreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
> com.google.gson.JsonObject elementos =  new com.google.gson.JsonObject();
> com.google.gson.JsonArray array = new com.google.gson.JsonArray();
>
> ```
>         while(rs.next()){
>             com.google.gson.JsonObject item = new com.google.gson.JsonObject();
>             item.addProperty("codigo", rs.getInt("estudiantes.Id_estudiante"));
>             //item.addProperty("codigo", rs.getString("estudiantes.Id_estudiante"));
>             item.addProperty("nombre", rs.getString("estudiantes.Name_users"));
>             item.addProperty("correo", rs.getString("estudiantes.Mail_users"));
>             item.addProperty("telefono", rs.getString("estudiantes.Phone_users"));
>             item.addProperty("estado", rs.getString("estudiantes.Estado_usuario"));
>             item.addProperty("campus", rs.getString("campus.Name_campus"));
>             item.addProperty("facultad", rs.getString("facultad.Name_faculty"));
>             item.addProperty("programa", rs.getString("programa.Name_program"));
>             item.addProperty("semestre", rs.getString("estudiantes.Semestre"));
>             item.addProperty("modalidad", rs.getString("estudiantes.Modalidad"));                
>             
>             array.add(item);                
>         }
>         
>         elementos.add("datos", array);
>         
>         out.print(elementos.toString());
>         
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>     }finally{
>         try {
>             if(conn != null) out.close();
>             if(ps != null) ps.close(); 
>             if(rs != null) rs.close();
>         } catch (SQLException e) {
>             System.out.println("Error 4: " + e);
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Se te olvido formatear el código de esta manera

```
Asi
```

Intenta formatear el ajax de esta manera

```
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../ConsultaEstudiantes",  //Se conecta a este archivo php que contiene alertas y la conexion
        cache:false,  
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",               
        success: function(response)  
        {  //Coloca un mensaje aqui
```